# How to customize babel 6 plugin/preset root

Tags: plugins, babeljs, preset

I have one `cli` project and one `boilerplate` project. Now I want to install all babel plugins and presets inside the `cli`, and use the `cli` to transpile the `boilerplate`.

The problem is, I'd like to run cli commands in boilerplate directory, and babel always looks for plugins/presets from boilerplate/node_modules instead of cli/node_modules.

How can I config babel to search only cli/node_modules?
I've tried to set `sourceRoot` and `moduleRoot`, but neither work.

Comment: Sorry, the tag for BabelJS is [tag:babeljs] not [tag:babel] so I didn't see this.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly pass the resolved plugins, e.g.

```
transform(code, {
    preset: [require('babel-preset-es2015')],
});
```

Comment: I don't suppose there is a way to do this with a `.babelrc`? I'm sure when babel 7 comes out it will allow this syntax in `.babelrc.js`, but until then is there any way to solve this?

Comment: If you've got a `.babelrc` in a project, that means the babel config is local to that project. You could make your own preset to do the resolution here, and then have the `.babelrc` load that preset though.